# Dropdown list in ASP MVC Kendo grid will not open

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to replicate exactly what is on [this Kendo demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom) with the Categories column. Simply a drop down list inside the grid. I copied all their source code exactly, but when I click the column with a drop down, the grid simply flashes. I *can* edit the FullName value fine. I tried to get an animation of the effect with a screen recorder, but for some reason it is not showing everything I see. In this image I am clicking the "Rol" drop down column multiple times.

[image: I am clicking the "Rol" drop down column multiple times]

What the gif does not show is that when I click the column, it briefly changes to a drop down control for a split second. I was able to capture this by adding a "debugger" line to the onDataBound event for the dropdown and taking a screenshot:

[image: frozen in the debugger]

What is going on? Why doesn't it just pop open?

Here is some of the relevant code:

The EditorTemplates/RolList.cshtml file. Note that NONE of these events fire except the onDataBound event. That is probably a clue.

```
@model MyCompany.Web.CaseLink.Mvc.Admin.Models.RolDropDown

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["roles"])
                        .DataValueField("RolId")
                        .DataTextField("RolDescription")
                        .Events(events => events
                            .Select("onSelect")
                            .Change("ddlChange")
                            .Open("onOpen")
                            .DataBound("onDatabound")                            
                         )
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSelect(e) {
        console.log("ddl select" + e);
    }

        function ddlChange(e) {
        console.log("ddl change" + e);
    }

        function onOpen(e) {
        console.log("ddl open" + e);
    }

            function onDatabound(e) {
            debugger;
        console.log("ddl databound" + e);
    }
</script>
```

Here is the partial view containing the MVC Grid itself. Note that the gridChange event was added just for debugging, and it does not fire when clicking in the drop down column.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CaseMemberGridRow>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.FullName)
            .Title("Name")
            ;

            columns.Bound(p => p.Rol).ClientTemplate("#=Rol.RolDescription#").Width(180);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Email)
            .Title("Email")
            ;
            columns.Bound(c => c.Telephone)
            .Title("Phone")
            ;
            columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolBar =>
        {
            toolBar.Create();
            toolBar.Save();
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler").Change("gridChange"))
            .Model(m =>
            {
                m.Field(p => p.FullName).Editable(true);
                m.Field(p => p.Rol).Editable(true);
                m.Field(p => p.Rol).DefaultValue(
                    ViewData["defaultRol"] as MyCompany.Web.CaseLink.Mvc.Admin.Models.RolDropDown);
            })
            .Create(create => create.Action("AddCaseMemberNoCustomerRecord_Create", "AddMember"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("AddCaseMemberNoCustomerRecord_Update", "AddMember"))
        )
)
```

Controller is nothing special, as I said, I am doing exactly when Telerik did in their demo. A sample:

```
    var roles = _rolService.GetAllRolesDTO()
        .OrderBy(o => o.Description)
        .Select(r => new RolDropDown
        {
            RolDescription = r.Description,
            RolId = r.RolId
        });
    ViewData["roles"] = roles;
    ViewData["defaultRol"] = roles.First();
```

If there is something to look for in the debugger on the "onDataBound" event, let me know. As you can see here, the datasource is definitely populated.
[image: debugger showing locals values]

EDIT: I am aware that you can attempt to do the same thing using the ForeignKey type of column. When I try that, I can get a drop down to work *once*. After selecting a value, the column starts acting like before where you cannot change the value.

```
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.RolId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["roles"], "RolId", "Description")
            .Title("Role")
            .Width(150);
```

Comment: I pasted your code into a test project(assuming the definitions of CaseMemberGridRow and RolDropDown) and it's working for me.  The only changes I made to your code were to add the Model.Id specification to the Grid(as you can't have an editable grid without specifying an Id field), commented out the Grid .Event()s and I moved the script block in RolList.cshtml above the DropDownListFor so that the functions exist before the trying to use them in the initialization.  Everything is just working....

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen I do have an Id field, I just removed it from the code I pasted for simplicity. the events are just for debugging. can you tell me, do the events in the drop down list fire all fire? this is weird..

Comment: So I tried it in Internet Explorer. If I rapidly click the drop down list column about 5-7 times, it will eventually turn into a drop down list. This is too bizarre. This is version 2016.3.1118.545